# R loop to query all tables within a database

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I am new to R and have a database, `DatabaseX` which contains multiple tables `a,b,c,d,etc`. I want to use R to count number of rows for a common attribute `message_id` among all these tables and store it separately.

I can count `message_id` for **all tables** using below code:

```
list<-dbListTables(con)
# print list of tables for testing
print(list)
for (i in 1:length(list)){
  query <- paste("SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM ",list[i], sep = "")
  t <- dbGetQuery(con,query)
}
print(t)
```

This prints :

```
### COUNT(message_id)
## 1  21519
```

but I want to keep record of `count(message_id)` for **each individual table**. So for example table a = 200, b = 300, c = 500, and etc.

any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "record?"

Comment: Have you tried using a nested loop. I would suggest writing a function that does the query and then putting that function in a recursive loop.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean to store the value in order to use it for future, I want to be able to draw a histogram to show number of message_id count in each table

Comment: @kaiten65 can you please explain a little more? I am new to R and not sure how to do this

Comment: @RainMan check my answer below. I have slightly modified your code but the principle is the same. You can achieve more with R when using functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kaiten65 suggested, one option would be to create a helper function which executes the `COUNT` query.  Outside of your loop I have defined a numeric vector `counts` which will store the number of records for each table in your database.  You can then perform descriptive stats on the tables along with this vector of record counts.

```
doCountQuery <- function(con, table) {
    query <- paste("SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM ", table, sep = "")
    t     <- dbGetQuery(con, query)

    return(t)
}

list <- dbListTables(con)
counts <- numeric(0)       # this will store the counts for all tables

for (i in 1:length(list)) {
    count <- doCountQuery(con, list[i])
    counts[i] <- count[[1]]
}
```

Comment: so the value of message_id count is stored in `counts[i]` for each table? I tried to do a `print(counts[i]` statement in the loop and I get this output `## [[1]]
## [1] 3
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] 12172
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] 2308
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] 3273
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] 21519` so there is no way to access the count for each individual table in future?

Comment: Try using `count[[1]]`, which should give you the (single) field coming back from the SQL query.

Comment: when printing the value, I get this `## [1] 3
## [1] 12172
## [1] 2308
## [1] 3273
## [1] 21519`I think I am confusing this with arrays, doesn't this mean value of [1] is changing ? can I output [1] 3 [2] 12172 [3] 2308?

Comment: `[1]` is just an index, the number which comes after it is the number of records for that particular table.  You can plot the vector of tables names against `counts` to get the output you want.

Comment: I added a few more tables and when I tried to run the query again I got this error : `error in .local(conn, statement,...) : could not run statement`. The error occurs in the for loop, any suggestion?

Comment: This sounds like either a problem with the query or the database connection itself.  Can you execute these queries directly from the MySQL database?

Comment: oh I noticed an error for tables with name like this `table-name`. To query that correctly I have to do this : `SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM  `table-name` `. I tried to change query to this : `query <- paste("SELECT COUNT(msgId) FROM `", table,"`", sep = "")` but I think it is wrong

Comment: My advice to you is to get the queries working in MySQL first, then worry about the R script.

Comment: are u in any IRC channel where I can contact you when you are free? I have a few quick questions, thanks

Comment: You can add me on Skype: tbiegeleisen ... but keep in mind I won't be in the office until tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions to achieve what you need. For instance

```
readDB <- function(db, i){
     query <- paste("SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM ",db, sep = "")
     t <- dbGetQuery(con,query)
     return(print(paste("Table ", i, " count:", t)
     }

list<-dbListTables(con)
for (i in 1:length(list)){
    readDB(list[i]);
}
```

This should print your list recursively but the actual code is in a nice editable function. Your output will be

```
 "Table 1 count: 2519"
 "Table 2 count: ---- "
```

More information on R functions here: http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html